# Why doesn't grep command work on text files with UTF-16 LE encoding?

Tags: utf-8, grep, utf-16

I want to save all the lines in a text file that start with certain string in another text file. So, I used this `grep` command to do that:

```
grep '^This' input.txt > output.txt
```

But the output file `output.txt` is empty though there are lot of lines in the file `input.txt` which start with the word 'this'. One of my mentor suggested that the file `input.txt` is in `UTF-16 LE` format and asked me to change it into `UTF-8`. Then the command worked well.

Why doesn't grep command work on files with `UTF-16 LE` format?

Comment: Check for BOM..

Comment: BOM?? Do you mean UTF-8 with BOM? It is working well with that too.

Comment: You say you have UTF 16 LE. Try `iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 myfile.txt | grep .......`

Comment: Is your command to convert the text file with UTF-16 LE encoding to UTF-8? Thanks. But I want to know why it doesn't work on files with UTF-16 LE encoding?

Answer (score 6):

`grep` is not encoding aware. It doesn't search for "characters", it searches for *bytes*. Your console is sending UTF-8/ASCII encoded text (same in this case for the string "^This") to `grep` to search for. If the file contains UTF-16 encoded text, that won't match, since the byte representations are different.

Comment: to grep into many files without having to convert them, ripgrep (rg) is the best choice https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep